# Data logging with the GPS and Bluetooth(App development)

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps

I'm working on a personal electronics project and I would like to create an app to log GPS data in addition to several other things.

The project is an automatic bicycle derailleur (it will shift gears automatically based on a number of factors such as speed, pedal cadence, gyroscope angle, etc). In addition I would like to create an app which will log things like speed, routes taken, number of hours ridden, etc. To save money, I would like to use my Android phone as both a screen for displaying some of these vitals as well as logging data with the GPS.

I'm very new to Android development, but my question is this: Would it be possible to tell the phone to automatically begin logging data (and possibly open the app, depending on what I decide) once it has been connected to the bike via bluetooth? And concurrently, I'd like it to stop and close the app once it's been disconnected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as I see it, is how you plan on connecting to the bike's Bluetooth radio.  Typically an application will initiate a Bluetooth connection (which is different from pairing.)  Running a service in the background looking for your Bluetooth device and connecting typically wouldn't be a good solution because searching for Bluetooth devices is very resource intensive.

You might be better off just having the connection initiate when the user starts the app.

The second part, to stop the app once the connection is dropped (becomes out of range, or the device on the bike drops the connection,) is quite straight forward.  Make a broadcast receiver:

```
public class DisconnectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(BasicDMMView.this, "Device disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Close anything you need to (log files etc.)
        finish();
    }

}
```

And then register the receiver once you've opened the bt connection:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
mReceiver = new DisconnectBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And don't forget to unregister the receiver when you leave the Activity:

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```